# Does there exist any command / symbol to display i++

Tags: symbols

`$i++$` doesn't look nice. Any better way?

Comment: Please provide a little context. Is this used for math, computer science or else? As software programming expression I would write it as `\texttt{i++}`.

Comment: From your previous questions I can tell it's about pseudocode typesetting. But it will not be obvious to other people. You should expand your question and its title to have sufficient information about what you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The traditional way to typeset assignments in pseudocode, including a modification of a variable, is to write them in the full form:

```
$i \gets i + 1$
```

[image: Result]

Alternatively, you can typeset a call to a function "Inc" or "Increment", or even use `\textbf{increment} $i$`, but it's disputable whether these variants will be more readable than the one the reader is accustomed to.